# NodeJs [Error] - ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed (node-oracledb)

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm trying to make multiple inserts of file data (example: 5 file of 1 million rows each one) into oracle database using [node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#getstarted).

When im almost finishing of insert the info, i got the following error:

```
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
```

I really don't know what is happening, because i already set the following variables of `node-oracledb` in 0 and still getting the error.

**Pool Configure:**

```
user: 'user1',
password: 'password1',
schema: 'DWH',
connectString: `${hostname}:${port}/${database_name}`,
poolMin: 1,
poolMax: 1,
poolIncrement: 0,
queueMax: 0,
poolTimeout: 0,
queueTimeout: 0
```

What other things i need to change to stop getting this error?

P.S.:

- I'm creating a new pool connection for every file
- I'm using `executeMany()`
- I'm using `worker_threads` to read each file and send the rows to the oracle method that create one connection for every file.

---

Versions:

- "oracledb": "^5.0.0"
- Node: v12.18.4
- Npm: 6.14.6
- Oracle Client installed in linux: 12.2.0

Comment: It's always worth getting the latest client library, just in case you've tickled a bug.  The 19.10 client will connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later.  I assume/hope you're using [`executeMany()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution).  Check you haven't exceeded a DB user resource profile limitation (though if this was true, I'd expect a different error).  Enable Oracle 'client' tracing and review the trace files.  Update your question with more detail about how you are handling connections and pools and parallelism. If the data is in files, why not use sqlloader?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Do you have any idea how to use `sqlloader` from nodejs?.

Comment: It's a separate command line tool.  It's available in various Oracle installs, including in Oracle Instant Client. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144  It lets you do things like ['direct path' loads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-conventional-and-direct-loads.html#GUID-7F0A089C-C98D-4B3B-9701-E1A3517C14DB).